# Printing Dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to print a Python3 dictionary using:

```
    b_result_page = []
    b_result_list = []
    b_result_page_and_list = {}

    #b_result page contains urls like: somesite.com?first=11
    for brp in b_result_page:
        LIST_SELECT = '.b_algo'
        for page_item_result in response.css(LIST_SELECT):
            NAME_SELECT = 'h2 a ::attr(href)'
            yield {
                'name' : page_item_result.css(LIST_SELECT).extract(),
            }
            #b_result_page_and_list is an empty dict, and im trying to append several page_item_result to its key.
            b_result_page_and_list.setdefault(brp, page_item_result)

    for k,v in b_result_page:
        print("key: {}  value:{}\n".format(k, v))
```

When I try to run this via `scrapy runspider scrape_b2.py`, I get an error of:

```
    for k,v in b_result_page:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You iterate over `b_result_page` twice - why do you expect a different number of things each time?

Comment: Documentation exists, and it's not difficult to read. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques

Comment: I'm certain that code doesn't produce that error message. In particular, `b_result_page` is an *empty* list, so the `for` loops never iterate. Please reduce your original program to the shortest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error. See [mcve] for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. You meant to loop over `b_result_page_and_list`
2. Looping over a dictionary only loops over its keys; you meant `for k, v in b_result_page_and_list.items():` to get both keys and values.

Comment: The thing is, `b_result_page_and_list` has nothing in it. Im trying to append a key of `brp` to it, with values in `page_item_result`

Comment: That's quite logical, since b_result_page is an empty list, so the first for loop (which loops over it) never does anything.

Comment: It gets appended values prior to looping, those values look like `somesite.com?first=11`, etc. let me comment my code to show you what i mean

Comment: Well, you don't show that in the question. Anyway then apparently `response.css('.b_algo')` is empty.

Comment: Added my comments

Comment: One thing is that the value of 'response' never changes.

Comment: so what are you saying?

Comment: Well I have no clue where `response` comes from or what `response.css` is, but I'm surprised it doesn't change based on the current URL in brp.

Comment: `response` comes from scrapy framework

Comment: But you don't show that in the question, so you're expecting us to be clairvoyant. I've had enough, time to sleep.